# How can I use a modded client on Minecraft Realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

When I was using earlier versions of 1.8, I had absolutely no issues whatsoever using a modded client. However, now when I try to use mods *(including ones that I need, like Optifine)*, I get a message informing me that my client is incompatible.

My main question is: **How can I use a modded client with Minecraft Realms?**

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty long issue, with many variables involved on how to solve it. Basically , Realms is blocking you for using a modified version of Minecraft - http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2lz7ed/optifine_not_working_with_realms/ - http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/servers/minecraft-realms/2179223-realms-client-oudate-is-it-a-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the replies on [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/realms/comments/2ko7re/realms_cant_use_optifine/) it looks like you just need to update. If it is Optifine you're using of course. If it's actually mods you'll just crash.

EDIT : After more research I found that mods are not allowed at all in Realms. And Minecraft did try to add Optifine, but judging by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/261801989246164993), Optifine did not want to be part of Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN** use optifine on a Realm I use it all the time you can also use Xaero's Minimap and other minimap mods, mods that only affect you. But it comes with crashing when opening ender chests.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried to use mods but after some research you cannot use them with realms yet. we will just have to wait for an update

Comment: Updates don't help, see other answer.